# How to run a program over multiple logins where each user can interact with it?

Tags: windows, authentication, windows-xp

Here is my scenario:
A user logs in to run a piece of software and later logs off. Later, a different user logs in  and wants to interact with this software that the previous user started.

I need this software to remain running across all the user logins so it is like they are all logging into an account that is running this piece of software. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: The software I need to run is made by a 3rd party that offers no API. I need it to be that software running across the multiple users.

Edit: I am sorry, but I edited your comment rather than adding my own.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what you are running, what language you are using, etc--it's hard to tell. To begin with when the very first user logs in, it should bring up a standard form where the user can then login. Let's call this the login form.

Next if the user successfully logs in, they are brought to where the application can be ran. Let's call this the application form.

If the user logs off and the application is still running, the application never really closes. It simply brings the user back to the login screen (for example, the application form has not started at launch. If user successfully logs in, user form is hidden--application launches and form is shown. If user logs out, application form is hidden--user form is shown BUT application still continues to run). If the next user has the correct credentials, it simply makes that already-running application visible again. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I can use C++ or C#. That is a good idea, but I need them to log off windows and then another user will come by and login with their windows account.

Initially, the idea was to login with your credentials, then it would forward you to a "central" user where the application is running. That way everyone has their own login, but logs into that one user. The problem is, I don't know how to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows XP, interactive services (and processes they launch) can behave in the way that you want.  Some applications will still shut themselves down anyway when the user logs out, if this is the case you may need to filter certain window messages and/or disable control-C handling.

You could try srvany.exe as a starting point, but for more information about writing your own service, [start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685141%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

This approach will not work in Windows Vista or later.